# How can I gracefully close all instances of gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I am trying to find out how to close all windows of Terminal (quit all instances of gnome-terminal) at once, cleanly. By "cleanly", I mean that it doesn't just simply kill all the instances at once, which is what I already have with this alias:

```
alias poof='/usr/bin/killall gnome-terminal'
```

What I want to do is to make it behave as the Terminal application behaves in Mac OS X. On that platform, when I hit "command-Q" (a/k/a "Apple-Q") in Terminal, all the windows are closed, but if there are processes running in any particular Terminal window, I get a dialog box warning me and asking me if I still want to close the window. This way I can make sure I don't kill a process I forgot about (e.g. editing a file with vim). In other words, it acts as though I have clicked the close button on each window.

This question has been asked in one form or another before, it has not been answered satisfactorily (unless I misunderstood the answer).  Surely there is a way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04? Either in the command line or using a keyboard shortcut (or both)?

(And please forgive me if I am not following any stylistic formats correctly, as I am new.)

Comment: I do not understand what your problem is. What happens if you use the command? Do you want to define a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Are the terminal windows (potentially) spread over different workspaces (viewports)?

Comment: @A.B. The problem is that even the "most friendly" kill command will kill the terminal(s) no matter if a process is running in it or not, while the manual Ctrl+Shift+Q will send a warning message with a choice option. OP wants to have that automatically for all terminal windows in one step automatically.

Comment: gracious1, did you manage, or is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried the script in your answer below, and it did kill the other terminals... but they had processes running in them! Only the front one worked. What I am hoping for is a way to get that dialog box for all the windows that have processes running.

Comment: I double-checked the behavior of Terminal Mac OS X. When you press `Command-Q`, the dialog box says, "You have <n> windows open which may contain  running processes." Then you have a choice of three buttons: "Terminate Processes", "Cancel", or "Review Windows". If you click this last button, then you are taken to each window in turn, with a dialog box that says, "Do you really want to close this window (Cancel) (Close)".
Perhaps I am wishing for the sun and the moon. At least I would like to get the dialog box for each window in turn. That would be ideal, just that much.

Comment: If the solutions given didn't work check my undeleted answer

Comment: Sorry, it had a little flaw before, now it's fixed. I tested it multiple times and it always worked, it quits all the windows but the current one (the one from which the script is launched).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your message; pleas @ping me if you are sending me a message. What I don't get, I am pretty sure the windows are not killed when an "unclosed"  process is running in it, tried it over and over again. Or do you mean you want the message also if the window is idle?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a process that ran in the terminal when it was killed? It basically just simulates Ctrl+Shift+Q

Answer (score 9):

Even the "friendliest" kill- command will close the terminal without asking. Also `man gnome-terminal` does not give any solution to close the window like in the GUI.

You can however make a script raise (all) `gnome-terminal` windows and simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

A complexity is that this will not work when the windows are spread over different workspaces. The script below therefore looks up the `gnome-terminal` windows on *the current* workspace and takes care of them as explained above.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

def get_res():
    # get resolution
    xr = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    pos = xr.index("current")
    return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

try:
    pid = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "gnome-terminal"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
except:
    pass
else:
    res = get_res()
    ws = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    for t in [w for w in ws if pid in w]:
        window = t.split()
        if all([0 < int(window[3]) < res[0], 0 < int(window[4]) < res[1]]) :
            w_id = window[0]    
            subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ia", w_id])
            subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Ctrl+Shift+Q"])
            time.sleep(0.2)
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `close_allterminals.py`.
3. Test-run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/close_allterminals.py
   ```

   Example: four `gnome-terminal` windows opened, in the top-left one is a process running:

   [image]

   After running the command, three are closed automatically, the one with the running process gets a prompt:

   [image]
4. If all works as you like, add it to a shortcut key combination:
   choose *System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts*. Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
    python3 /path/to/close_allterminals.py
   ```

---

#### *Edit*

The version below also takes care of `gnome-terminal` windows on other workspace: all windows are moved to the current workspace before they are closed in a safe way.

An example:
I have in total six `gnome-terminal` windows open on four different workspaces, many of them have processes running in it:

[image]

If I run the script, all `gnome-terminal` windows are orderly moved to the current workspace and raised. Idle windows are closed automatically, the ones with a running process are prompted:

[image]

#### The script

Set it up like the first version.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

def get_res():
    # get resolution
    xr = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").split()
    pos = xr.index("current")
    return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

try:
    pid = subprocess.check_output(["pidof", "gnome-terminal"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
except:
    pass
else:
    res = get_res()
    ws = subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    matches = [t.split() for t in [w for w in ws if pid in w]]
    pos = 100
    for match in matches:
        w_id = match[0]
        subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowmove", "--sync", match[0], str(pos), str(pos/2) ])
        subprocess.call(["wmctrl", "-ia", w_id])
        subprocess.call(["xdotool", "key", "Ctrl+Shift+Q"])
        pos = pos+100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this simple shell script `close_terminals`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
xdotool search --class "terminal" | while read id
do
      xdotool windowactivate "$id" &>/dev/null
      xdotool key ctrl+shift+q
      sleep 0.2
done
```

Then create a new shortcut and call this script.

Comment: Thank you for trying. This is close but like Jacob's script, I get a dialog box only for the active window. I can actually see a use for something like your script or Jacob's, come to think of it, so thank you. But if you read my comments to the question, you might see what I am looking for is a way to get the dialog boxes to appear with each window. Is this possible?