# How to exit all terminal instances (keyboard shortcut) Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I'm reiterating the question from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608914/closing-all-instances-of-terminal-at-once-cleanly) on purpose.  I don't have the reputation to write a comment, sorry!

I found a keyboard shortcut for killing all Terminal windows and it prompts me to confirm that I want to close if Vim or some other program is open!  Unfortunately, I don't know which keys I press; it happened accidentally.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

This question has been asked in one form or another before, including [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608914/closing-all-instances-of-terminal-at-once-cleanly).  What is the actual keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl+Shift+Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the comment by Sourav Ghosh,

### Some more helpful terminal shortcuts:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to kill all
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to kill one
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to make a new terminal pointing at the same directory
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to make a new terminal in a tab pointing at the same directory

Comment: Do you mean [the comment by dessert](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987822/how-to-exit-all-terminal-instances-keyboard-shortcut-ubuntu-16-04#comment1591325_987822)? Sourav Ghosh has made no comment I can see.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + Q only killed one terminal for me